# Android Studio "Function invocation 'LayoutInflater(...)' expected"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am a novice at android studio and I am trying to make a simple Business Card App.

the issue is an error message that says:

```
Function invocation 'LayoutInflater(...)' expected
```

This is my main activity file:

```
package com.example.appcartodevisita.ui

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import com.example.appcartodevisita.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val binding by lazy {ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater)}

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(binding.root)
       insertListener()
   }
}
```

This is my AddBusinessCardActivity:

```
package com.example.appcartodevisita.ui

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import com.example.appcartodevisita.databinding.ActivityAdicionarCartaoBinding
import com.example.appcartodevisita.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class AddBusinessCardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val binding by lazy { ActivityAddBusinessCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater)}

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(binding.root)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is case-sensitive, as are most computer programming languages.

Replace:

```kotlin
private val binding by lazy {ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater)}
```

with:

```kotlin
private val binding by lazy {ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)}
```

IOW, use the lowercase `l` for `layoutInflater`, not the uppercase `L` for `LayoutInflater`.